# Getting error while executing cloud-init commands in Terraform

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, terraform, cloud-init

We are upgrading Terraform to 1.3.7 version and trying to use the below piece of code under the cloud-init section of an ec2-instance to setup a disk based on the conditional value. If the **var.load_ldp_data_from_volume** is false then perform the disk setup commands if the value is true, do nothing.

```
${var.load_ldp_data_from_volume == false ? "
   disk_setup:
      /dev/${var.ldp_device_name}:
        table_type: mbr
        layout: false
        overwrite: false
  fs_setup:
      - label: /var/lib/ldap
        filesystem: ext4
        device: /dev/${var.ldp_device_name}
        partition: none
        overwrite: false" : "" }
```

When we add this code and execute the terraform initialization command then it is giving the below error.

```
Error: Invalid multi-line string

On modules/cmx_developer/ldp/main.tf line 112: Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a
multi-line string, either use the \n escape to represent a newline character or use the "heredoc" multi-line template
syntax.


Error: Invalid multi-line string

On modules/cmx_developer/ldp/main.tf line 113: Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a
multi-line string, either use the \n escape to represent a newline character or use the "heredoc" multi-line template
syntax.


Error: Invalid multi-line string

On modules/cmx_developer/ldp/main.tf line 114: Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a
multi-line string, either use the \n escape to represent a newline character or use the "heredoc" multi-line template
syntax.


Error: Unterminated template string

On modules/cmx_developer/ldp/main.tf line 104: No closing marker was found for the string.

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-224 devops-dev-shared-terraform]$
```

The same code was used in the previous terraform 0.11.3 version but we didn't see any issues/errors like above but only problem was once the code was deployed we used to not see the mount points created or the file system was not setup and we have been doing the steps manually once the ec2 instance is completely up. We see the code what we are using for the **disk_setup** is valid and the same is mentioned in the cloud-init documentation https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html under **disk_setup** section. But not sure why it was not working.

Can anyone please check and let us know what might be the issue?

Is the syntax we are using not correct?

Is there any other way to use in the cloud-init section to perform the disk_setup commands?

Pasting few lines before and after the code for your reference:-

```
    - if [ false == false ];then ./tmp/attach_volume.sh $device_name ;else echo "LDP is true, so not loading from volume" >> /tmp/do_nothing.txt;fi
       - mkdir -p /var/lib/ldap
  ${var.load_ldp_data_from_volume == false ? "
   disk_setup:
      /dev/${var.ldp_device_name}:
        table_type: mbr
        layout: false
        overwrite: false
  fs_setup:
      - label: /var/lib/ldap
        filesystem: ext4
        device: /dev/${var.ldp_device_name}
        partition: none
        overwrite: false" : "" }
  EOF

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      ebs_block_device]
  }
```

We are expecting the volume to be attached

```
- if [ false == false ];then ./tmp/attach_volume.sh $device_name ;else echo "LDP is true, so not loading from volume" >> /tmp/do_nothing.txt;fi
- mkdir -p /var/lib/ldap
  **setup_disk = <<EOF**
```

${var.load_ldp_data_from_volume == false ? "
disk_setup:
/dev/${var.ldp_device_name}:
table_type: mbr
layout: false
overwrite: false
fs_setup:
- label: /var/lib/ldap
filesystem: ext4
device: /dev/${var.ldp_device_name}
partition: none
overwrite: false" : "" }
**EOF**
EOF

Comment: As the error suggested, did you try to use the "heredoc" multi-line template
syntax? Also, the mismatched EOF looks wrong. Note that the title is misleading, since these are errors in terraform, not cloud-init. You might consider updating the title to get better answers.

Comment: @BrettHolman I've added the heredoc code above, Please check and let me know whether it looks good or not. And I've also tried using newline character(\n) at the end of each line but didn't work.

Comment: @BrettHolman updated the title accordingly